# Armstrong Number in C#

Tags: c#, math

I wrote this program in C# to generate Armstrong numbers.I know the addition of extra method is unnecessary but it's something I've just learnt and have been practicing . So the generator only shows number till 9 no matter how large of a limit I give.

```
using System;

namespace ArmstrongNumberGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the maximum limit for searching");
            int max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                if (isArmstrong(i))
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static bool isArmstrong(int x)
        {
            int temp = x;
            int sum = 0;
            while (x!=0)
            { sum = sum + x % 10;
                x = x / 10;
            }

            if (sum == temp)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please clarify expected inputs/outputs, and what is happening?

Comment: It doesn't give me a compile error but when I enter max limit as 153, it gives out 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 rather than 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,153

Comment: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sP5Sxu) for the curious...

Comment: "sum = sum + x % 10;
                x = x / 10;" are you sure this is right formula for Amstrong Number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation for Armstrong-Number:

> Sum of the cubes of its digits must equal to the number itself.

For example, `407` is given as input.
`4 * 4 * 4 + 0 * 0 * 0 + 7 * 7 * 7 = 407` is an armstrong number.

You need to calculate the sum right:

```
static bool isArmstrong(int x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = x; i > 0; i = i / 10)
    {
        sum = sum + (int)Math.Pow(i % 10, 3.0);
    }

    if (x == sum)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This has following output with your code (except that i incluced `0` which is also an armstrong number):

```
Enter the maximum limit for searching
9999
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
```

Comment: is there a function in C# for powers like pow() in the math.h of C?

Answer (score 1):

Your isAmstrong formula itself seems to be wrong.

Try to use summation of Math.Pow(x % 10, 3) instead of this:

```
sum = sum + x % 10;
x = x / 10;
```

Use

```
sum = sum + Math.Pow(x % 10, 3);
x = x / 10;
```

Checkout Amstrong Number:

http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html

Answer (score 0):

You never check your number length power with current digit because [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) says;

> In recreational number theory, a Armstrong number is a
>   number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the **power of
>   the number of digits**.

I fixed your method based on that like;

```
static bool isArmstrong(int x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int tempX = x;
    int temp = 0;
    int length = x.ToString().Length;

    while (x != 0)
    {
        temp = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        sum += (int)Math.Pow(temp, length);
    }

    if (sum == tempX)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

For example, if you call all armstrong numbers less than `10000`, with

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
{
     if (isArmstrong(i))
         Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

you will get

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int num=407;
    int nnum=num;
    string ss = num.ToString();
    int a=0;
    int b=0;string aa=" ";
    double newA=0;

    for(int i=0 ; i < ss.Length ; i++)
    {
        if(num > 0)
        {
            if(num < 10)
            {
                num = num+10;

            }
                a=num%10;
                aa += a+" ,";
                string s = num.ToString();
                string str=s.Remove(s.Length-1,1);
                s=str;
                b=int.Parse(s);
                newA += Math.Pow(a,3);
                Console.WriteLine("((({0})))",newA);
                num=b;
                Console.WriteLine(aa);
                num=int.Parse(str);
    }
            if(nnum==newA)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n {0} is a strong number .... !",nnum);
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written the below code to find whether the given number is a Armstrong number or not and it worked fine

Created a new static method named Armstrong with a string parameter

```
public static void Armstrong(string i)
        {
            double k=0;
            for (int j = 0; j < i.Length; j++)
            {
                k = k + Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToString(i[j])), i.Length);
            }

            if (k == int.Parse(i))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Armstrong");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Armstrong");
            }
        }
```

If we call the method in Main method then we can get the required output

Armstrong("153");

Result :Armstrong

Similarly if we want to find whether a number is armstrong or not then keep the required number as arguments of the method and execute